# Heroku says my custom domain is already in use, despite having already released it

Tags: heroku

When I attempt to add a new custom domain to my heroku app, I receive the following error

```
Domain "..." could not be created:
... is currently in use by another app.
```

See this image:
[Example of error in the add new domain sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP6xE.png)

Details so far:

1. I use a free dyno for my app
2. I own the domain and do not use it in any other heroku app (in fact, it's unused for any website)
3. I used this form, [Heroku Domain Release](https://tools.heroku.support/domain-release), to release the domain from any existing usage on Heroku. This was successful and seems to imply it was in use by another app at some point.
4. I ran that form again, and received the message that it was no longer in use by any app.

It's been at least an hour since I tried using the release form and I still receive the same error message when trying to add my domain.

I cannot contact Heroku support directly since I use a free dyno.

Any help greatly appreciated!